# Selecting an option from two separate states

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two separate `states`: an `array` and a `string`. After clicking on one of the elements it gets a class `highlight` and becomes `selected`. How can I display `selected`: an item from an `array` or a `string`.

In this case: I would like to be able to select (add class highlight after clicking) paragraph number 6.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj2L0ny1/).

```js
var items = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  items.push({
    id: i
  })
}
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items,
    selected: undefined,
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

```css
li.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

p,
h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :class="{highlight:item == selected}" @click="selected = item">{{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>6</p>

  <h1>Selected item: {{ this.selected }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I could not get what you mean in *How can I display selected: an item from an array or a string.* part of your question. What extra thing do you want in your fiddle, it is not crystal clear to me.

Comment: I would like to be able to select (add class `highlight` after clicking) a paragraph `number 6`.

Comment: What is the exact expected behaviour? I see the click handler select and show the selected

Comment: Paragraph with the digit `6` is outside of the `v-for` loop but I would like somehow to display it after clicking on `6` in `Selected item:`

Comment: I would give the item itself a property selected and in the markup you can just do like `v-bind:class="{ active: item.selected }"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you want to display `6` also when click ... If so you can assign same data type like `{id: 6}` on click .

```js
var items = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  items.push({
    id: i
  })
}
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items,
    selected: undefined,
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

p,
h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :class="{highlight:item == selected}" @click="selected = item">{{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p :class="{highlight: selected && selected.id === 6}" @click="selected = {id: 6}">6</p>

  <h1>Selected item: {{ this.selected }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks!